# Spring - How to read multiple messages off the queue and persist them in bulk

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, solace

I'm trying to improve the performance of the system built with (Spring Integration + Solace messaging system) by reading the messages off the queue in bulk (let's say 50 at a time) and persisting them into the DB (in bulk).
When I use a Spring Integration poller in inbound-channel-adapter with the below config:

> ```
> <int:poller
>     messages-per-poll="100"
>     rate="1000"
> />
> ```

I have 2 issues:

1. In ServiceActivator I will still need to receive one message at a
   time  (ServiceActivator method doesn't allow method declaration with
   List> parameter
2. Even by reading 1 message at a time I can't collect them into a list
   (by 50) to persist in bulk, because there might be only 40 messages
   on the queue and I would need to (infinitely) wait for another 10 to
   persist.

I tried to solve that with com.solacesystems.jcsmp.FlowReceiver, it has a drawback that I can't receive the message headers.

What can you suggest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Aggregator` EIP is for you. It can be configured to group messages to `50` let's say by the `Thread.currentThread.getId()` as correlation key. And also it can release groups by the fact "empty" message via `AbstractMessageSourceAdvice.afterReceive()`:

```
/**
 * Subclasses can take actions based on the result of the poll; e.g.
 * adjust the {@code trigger}. The message can also be replaced with a new one.
 * @param result the received message.
 * @param source the message source.
 * @return a message to continue to process the result, null to discard whatever the poll returned.
 */
public abstract Message<?> afterReceive(Message<?> result, MessageSource<?> source);
```

So, when result is `null`, you should trigger `MessageGroupStoreReaper` to expire non-50 groups in the aggregator.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#aggregator).

Comment: Thanks for quick answer!